# How to keep common variable for all users in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to create a web application with Laravel.

In the app there is a variable X which can be updated by every user and it should be seen to every user.

For example if initial value of X is 1 and first user change it to 10 then the second user should see the value of X as 10.

How can I store variable X so it is common for all users?
So far what I did is store it in a database or a file. But is there other elegant method to do this?

Comment: Why do you think that storing to a db is not elegant?

Comment: Do I have to create a whole table for single variable?

Comment: For something that's updated by an unknown amount of users, yes, you need something that allows multiple access to a single source. You're free to go on ahead and come up with a different approach, but you won't make anything "more elegant" simply because it's impossible. Be it a table or a text file, it's basically the same thing - multiple users, single source of data. It's simply easier to work with a database. Good luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put the value into the cache:

```
Cache::rememberForever('someVar', 'value');
```

Then you can retrive it by:

```
Cache::get('someVar');
```

This will provide you value until the cache will clear.

Comment: It's not a good idea since you need sometimes clear app cache for some reason (actually, there are a lot of reasons for doing this) and you'll lost data.

Comment: yes of course you'll lost it.... but keeping it in config (as you suggest) has nothing to passing the varibles between the users :)

Comment: If you keep variable in config, you have access to it from any user, from part of an app.

Comment: If I understood OP correctly, he wants to give access to a single variable to all users, so everyone could change this variable and see what value it has now: `In the app there is a variable X which can be updated by every user and it should be seen to every user.`

Comment: OK and now tell me... how one user (client from browser) can set a config so that other user (other browser) can access to the changed value of that config?

Comment: Maybe you think about the user as a developer of this app?

Comment: Config files are global, they are the same for all users. https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/configuration

Comment: Yes and you cannot change and pass the value between the users :)

Comment: Why not? It's kind of global variable accessible for every request and it doesn't depend on user. Even request with non authenticated user has access to it.

Comment: It's global but also static. You store this value in php file. Of corse if you have for example config in db then your solution should work

Comment: Cache::get('someVar'); gives updated value for every user of site?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`config()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/configuration#accessing-configuration-values) helper to use config file to store this variable.

```
// Get X variable.
$x = config('custom.x');
```

You also can set X variable at runtime and [save it](http://heera.it/laravel-tips-update-config-runtime-persistently#.V7_58CdZwjE).

In this case, variable will be stored in `config/custom.php` file.

Comment: but still for new user the vaiable X starts from 1

Comment: As I understood from your question, there is only one variable X, so `config()` is perfect for this. If you have X for each user, use DB with separate table or keep X in `users` table.

Comment: what you understood is correct. but using this method it didn't happen

Comment: Please read updated answer. It's still a best way if you have just one global variable for all users.